# Assigning multiple integers to a character array in binary

Tags: c++

I have three integers (4 bytes of memory for each integer) and I want to assign each of their binary values to a character array with 12 elements. So, if each integer had a value of let's say 2, then I want the character array to have these values:

```
2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0
```

I have tried:

```
memcpy(cTemp, &integer1 + &integer2 + &integer3, 12);
```

but I receive an "invalid operands" compiler error.

I have also found the function strcat referenced here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/

However it is mentioned as: "The terminating null character in destination is overwritten by the first character of source" which I obviously don't want since most of the times integers will have a null character at the end unless the value is really large. Does anybody know of a better working method? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If this is homework, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Perhaps that might help others find a better solution.

Comment: What's with people that keep saying I'm asking help for homework? It's for a personal project, I've never even taken a programming class before.
@Void In my particular case I want to output the integers into a file in binary because the file itself is not developed by me, I'm just writing a program to edit said file, and the file happens to store integers in binary.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see how a variable is represented as a sequence of bytes, you can do the following.

```
int i[3] = {2, 2, 2};
char cTemp[sizeof i];
memcpy(cTemp, &i, sizeof i);
```

Note however that the representation will be different on different platforms. What are you trying to solve?

**Edit:**

> I'm just writing a program to edit [a file], and the file happens to store integers in binary.

Why didn't you say so in the first place? If you know the program will only run on platforms where `int` has the correct memory-layout, you can simply store the integer.

```
fout.write((char const *)&i, sizeof i);
```

However, if you want to be portable, you need to properly serialize it.

```
void store_uint32_le(char * dest, unsigned long value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        *dest++ = value & 0xff;
        value >>= 8;
    }
    assert(value == 0);
}

int main()
{
    char serialized[12];
    store_uint32_le(serialized, 2);
    store_uint32_le(serialized + 4, 2);
    store_uint32_le(serialized + 8, 2);

    std::ofstream fout("myfile.bin", std::ios::binary);
    fout.write(serialized, sizeof serialized);
}
```

Comment: That will assign the binary value of 2 once to a character array of 4 elements. That's not what I want.

Comment: There you go. Or did I misunderstood the question? Perhaps you could clarify.

Comment: I've tried this method, and it only appears to copy the memory of the first element of i. I've even tried changing the third parameter of memcpy to 12.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you're initializing `i` with `{2, 2, 2}` and not `{2}`?

Comment: Yes. To tell if it worked or not I outputted the contents of cTemp into a file using ofstream, and I only got 2 0 0 0.

Comment: You mean `cTemp` only has 4 elements? You'll probably need to show some code. The snippet in my answer works fine and should work under any compliant compiler.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably simpler (if you are on a x86 at least :P) to just cast the pointer and assign directly. i.e.

```
int* p = (int*) cTemp; 
p[0] = a;
p[1] = b;
p[2] = c;
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior and will fail on most platforms (those which dislike unaligned access).

Comment: hence the point I made about requiring x86 platforms, still it is worth pointing out that _most_ platforms are x86 these days anyway.

Comment: Most *desktop* platforms are x86-based. And it is still undefined behavior even on those.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do a union hack:

```
union translate {
    char c[sizeof(int) * 3];
    int i[3];
};

translate t;
t.i[0] = 2;
t.i[1] = 2;
t.i[2] = 2;

// access t.c[x] to get the chars
```

... and read the chars...

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
int i,j,k;

char a[12];

*((int*)a) = i;
*(((int*)a)+1) = j;
*(((int*)a)+2) = k;
```

Comment: Like tyranid, this is undefined behavior.

Comment: I presume you mean that some platform might word-align the char array elements. Because arrays are defined as contiguous, that would mean sizeof(char)==word_length (e.g. 4). Could you give me an example of an architecture for which this is true?

Comment: abc, the standard does not define the behavior of code that accesses objects of dynamic type `int` through l-values of static type `char`. That's why the behavior is undefined. And implementation are not allowed to add padding between elements of an array.

Comment: Could you explain your answer in more detail please? Dynamic typing (as defined here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_typing#Dynamic_typing) does not exist in c++. It would also help if you could point me to the relevant passage in the standard. Thanks.